# How to import data from text file into PGSQL database table?

Tags: php, postgresql, text

I am trying to import data from a text file into my pgsql database table. none of  is imported.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_dataku user=postgres password=S3cr3t179");// Check connection

$handle = fopen($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"], "r");
if ($handle)
{
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) 
    {

     $lineArr = explode("\t", "$line");
     var_dump($lineArr);
     // instead assigning one by onb use php list -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php            
     list($nmr_fingerprint, $tgl_presensine, $pegawai_idne, $validasi_a, $validasi_b, $stat) = $lineArr;

     // and then insert data
     $query_insert = "INSERT INTO employee (nmr_fingerprint,tgl_presensine,pegawai_idne,validasi_a,validasi_b,stat) VALUES ('$nmr_fingerprint','$tgl_presensine','$pegawai_idne','$validasi_a','$validasi_b','$stat')";
    }
        $insert = pg_query($query_insert);
        $content.= "<div class='success' id='message'>Berhasil di import</div>";
}
fclose($handle);
$content.= <<<EOF
<h4>Import Data</h4>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    File:<input name="uploaded" type="file" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="upfile" value="Upload File">
</form>
EOF;
echo $content;
```

My Table :
[image: My Postgresql Table]

My TXT file :

[image: My TXT file]

The result of my code :
[image: The result of my code]

Comment: Please use a little text as images as possible.  Like your table, could be cut-paste and formatted as code here.

Comment: @Nic3500 ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turn on logging so you can see what sql postgresql is being presented with. In ../data/postgresql.conf change the setting below and restart postgresql. Note - remove the #

```
#log_min_duration_statement = -1    # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

Comment: hi Slumdog,  I have remove the #  log_min_duration_statement = 0 and restart postgresql, but I have not result for the import. Any other suggest?

Comment: but if text file only 10 row, I can import the last one of text   [link](https://snag.gy/Ijmh1Z.jpg)  and this is the result in my table on postgresql [link](https://snag.gy/bysrIc.jpg)

Comment: What do you see in the logs if you have logging turned on? Logs are somewhere like ..\PostgreSQL\data\log folder

Comment: hi @slumdog, I can not find log folder in my ubuntu server...I have repeate to restart postgresql    [link](https://snag.gy/kAMZq6.jpg)

Comment: Interesting, .... run this sql "show data_directory; " then run "show log_directory; ". I would expect the log folder to be under the data folder but I guess it might be anywhere, the sql should tell you.